# Wamp Server phpmyadmin blank screen

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp, port, conflict

I read many things about this problem but i didn't find a solution. I have Wamp and Bitnami installed on the same PC , and i think this brings me into a conflict problem. However , i changed my Apachi Wamp port from 80 into 8888. So when i write l`ocalhost:8888` i can see the main wamp page. If i write `localhost:8888/phpmyadmin` i have a blank page. I also tried to write `http:localhost:8888/phpmyadmin` , but nothing seems to work. I don' want to unistall Bitnami. What should i do to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you looked in the error logs, Apache and PHP? If not then have a look

Comment: http://xfloyd.net/blog/?p=515 Maybe you missed one point